# Show div at mouse click position, accounting for scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I want to be able to show a div inside a scrollable parent div wherever the mouse is clicked. I tried implementing JAVAGeek's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245119/how-to-get-mouse-pointer-position-using-javascript-for-internet-explorer) (using the `tempX` and `tempY` values to specify the `left` and `top` attributes of the div's CSS) but it doesn't account for scrolling properly, i.e. if I scroll down in the parent div and click the div doesn't appear where I clicked. How do I show a div at the absolute position of my click even if it's inside of a scrollable parent? Thanks

Comment: can you show us the HTML and CSS you are using? Based on your description, it sounds like it might be an issue of 'position' on the div that appears, and the scrollable parent. e.g. your scrollable parent is position relative, and the div that appears is absolute.

Comment: I'm just getting the `tempX` and `tempY` values from the code I linked in the question and assigning those values to the `top` and `left` properties of the div, and setting the position to absolute. The parent div  is just a normal div with a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: what is the next parent element with position:relative declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: turns out I was adding the offset of the body's scroll position instead of the parent div's. For example, what was once

```
tempY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
```

is now

```
tempY = e.clientY + $( ".parent-div" ).scrollTop();
```