# How can I get the coordinates of a click on the screen

Tags: c#, coordinates, desktop, bots

i'm trying to automate some actions with a c# bot. The program should work in this way:

a. the user add actions to a list of actions that the bot will use after the setup.
b. for example the user add the "auto-click" action.
c. then the program hide his window to let the user click and get the coordinates.

Now, I know how to hide the program window but I don't know how to manage how to get the coordinates of the screen when the user clicks. do anybody know how to achieve this?

Edit: my question is a bit different from the one posted below, i'm not trying to detect mouse clicks in the main form...

Comment: Use something to hook mouse clicks to get the coordinates of the mouse like this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055211/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-click

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you might be looking for this

[How to get mouse pointer position using javascript for internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245119/how-to-get-mouse-pointer-position-using-javascript-for-internet-explorer)

One of the answer conrtains cross browser solution not just IE.

Comment: He asked for a way in C#, not a browser way.