# How do I alert the content of a DIV without using an alert?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a program that basically shows the coordinates of a point when someone mouses over it and then makes it disappear when the mouse pointer is off the element. I have tried to do this with alert boxes but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to close them. I've looked around and people have said something about using DIVS but I have no idea where to start. This is for a introductory programming course so PLEASE no Jquery, only pure JavaScript.

```
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("point" + i).style.left = x[i] + "px";
        }
        var html;
        html = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
        {
            document.getElementById("point" + i).onmouseover = onmouseover;
        }
    }

};
function onmouseover() {
    var x;
    x = window.alert("X: " + this.style.left + " ," + "Y: " + this.style.top);
    this.onmouseover = function () { setHTML(element, x) };
}
```

Comment: can I see some javascript code which you tried??

Comment: may be you can create tooltips which is displayed on mouse over the element and hides when off the element..!

Comment: Can you please post an example of that?

Comment: Tooltip is one of the best options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a div at the end of the page with a specific ID and use CSS to position it absolutely (you'll want to adjust top and left accordingly)...

```
<div id="alert" style="position:absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; display: none;"></div>
```

...then in your Javascript, instead of calling an alert, you can show and hide your div.

```
document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block"; // display the div

document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none"; // hide the div
```

You could also base the position off of cursor position instead of having it be fixed if you want.  [How to get mouse pointer position using javascript for internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245119/how-to-get-mouse-pointer-position-using-javascript-for-internet-explorer)