# Line of code that is changing the DOM element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I want to know how to pinpoint the line/position of code which is altering a specific DOM element or it's style.
With Chrome DOMListner I see which elements get changed and what is the change but I cannot figure out which line of script caused that DOM change.

**Example**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnnzgq8d/)

HTML

```
<div class="red circle absolute"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.red {
    background-color: #F44336;
    /* Material design 500 tint Red color */
 }
.circle {
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS

```
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    // source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245119/how-to-get-mouse-pointer-position-using-javascript-for-internet-explorer
    // as on: 28.09.2015
    var x = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    var y = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);

    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    el.style.left = (x - 15) + 'px';
    el.style.top = (y - 15) + 'px';
}
```

jsfiddle shows a circle which follows the mouse cursor. Circle is positioned absolutely and onmousemove event triggers the change of circle position. This example is over-simplified and one can easily see where the top and left properties of a DOM element are changed.

I would like to find a method of finding the exact line/position of code for any JS script I stumble upon. Thanks

Comment: can't you see call stack in any point in debugger when you stop on the change?

Comment: I was unaware of the option that James Brierley gave. Now I can see the callstack :) . Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome's developer tools, this option is available if you right click on a specific element.  Selecting `Break on...` and then one of the sub-options will cause Chrome to break on the JavaScript line that made the change, so long as you had the tools open at the time.

[image]

Comment: Similarly, you might find [object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) helpful to see where a property is changed.